# How to pagebreak after displaying each 10 keys from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, page-break

I am using PHP have an array with 100 keys, and I want to echo all the keys, however, I want to add a 
 after displaying every 10th key: keys 1-10 (0-9), 11-20,  21-30...so on.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the [Modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator:

```
if (!($key % 10)) {
    // page break
}
```